# Getting the "more" tag to work with plugin-list-category-post

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I know the List category posts has an attribute to show only an excerpt from the post, but I can't seem to get the plugin to work for the Wordpress  tag break.  Does the plugin recognize the  tag?

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you are asking if you can get the [List category posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) to recognize the  tag then you can use the ["get_extended()" function in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended).

Create a new List category template and then use the following code to get the part of the post before the more tag for display.

```
$moreTag = get_extended($single->post_content);
$beforeMore = $moreTag['main'];
```

If you are interested I am creating a List category template for use with the TwentyTen theme - specifically for use with a page template that will be used to display WordPress pages in custom Facebook tabs.  Let me know and I'll get it to you.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that now.  And for the WP/Facebook items - yes, I'm interested!

Comment: Ok - here is the code for the "latest posts" TwentyTen theme List category template. https://gist.github.com/1401538